# Magento 2 - how to load JS template from filesystem in jquery widget

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

For example, native Magento theme-frontend-blank\web\js\navigation-menu.js has such code:

```
$.widget('mage.navigationMenu', {
    options: {
    ...
        collapsableDropdownTemplate:
            '<script type="text/x-magento-template">' +
                '<li class="level0 level-top more parent">' +
                    '<div class="submenu">' +
                        '<ul><%= elems %></ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</script>'
```

And then they do

```
        this.collapsableDropdown = $(
            mageTemplate(
                this.options.collapsableDropdownTemplate,
                {elems: this.elemsToCollapseClone}
            )
        );
```

**Is it possible to do something like this**

**collapsableDropdownTemplate: getTemplate(some_relative_path_to_template) ?** 
instead of

```
        collapsableDropdownTemplate:
            '<script type="text/x-magento-template">' +
                '<li class="level0 level-top more parent">' +
                    '<div class="submenu">' +
                        '<ul><%= elems %></ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</script>'
```

My template is a little bit bigger and I want to allow frontend developers to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do it.

1) Template selector: the script and template are in one place.

Using `text/x-magento-template`

**vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking.phtml**

```
<script id="track_row_template" type="text/x-magento-template">

......

trackingControl.template = mageTemplate('#track_row_template');
```

2) Require text (I think you need it)

**vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/thumbnail.js**

Define it: `text!Magento_Ui/templates/grid/cells/thumbnail/preview.html`

```
define([
    './column',
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
    'text!Magento_Ui/templates/grid/cells/thumbnail/preview.html',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (Column, $, mageTemplate, thumbnailPreviewTemplate) {
```

Use it

```
var modalHtml = mageTemplate(
            thumbnailPreviewTemplate,
            {
                src: this.getOrigSrc(row), alt: this.getAlt(row), link: this.getLink(row),
                linkText: $.mage.__('Go to Details Page')
            }
        );
```

See here: **vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js**